# how to check if a phone number is valid whatsapp number in Android?

Tags: android, whatsapp

so I have an edit text that will be used as a view to get phone number from user, say if the phone number is +6123456789 , I want to check if this number has whatsapp number or not,i want to avoid the user to input fake whatsapp number, how to do that ?

Answer (score 6):

Update (Nov 2022):

Whatsapp are repurposing the contacts node starting in v2.43 to no longer provide status information about a phone number. Regardless of whether a user has WhatsApp, it will always return valid for status in the response. [For more information see official docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/contacts)

original answer:

You must have: [Facebook Whatsapp Business Api for contacts check](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/contacts)

Once you have a valid business account you could then query the `Contact`. You will get all the details in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp).

Hope it works for you!

Comment: is it free to perform phone number checking like this ? thank you very much for your information :)

Comment: but from the documentation in here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/contacts . it is said that: "If you check too many phone numbers without sending to them, you will be banned"

Comment: Interesting. Any idea how many (Too many phone number) means?

Comment: there's a limitation for several period of time i guess....

Comment: so basically after Update (Nov 2022) we can never ever check if the phone number is valid or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this service https://watverifyapi.live 
It allows you to verify multiple whatsapp number at a time.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32862786)

Comment: Is this still working after WhatsApp changes to the contacts node mentioned by on the answer above?

Comment: Yes still working so far I tested but its a paid service

Comment: What is the response time on this API?

Answer (score 0):

You can send a message to the phone number that you want to check, and if you get the 131026 error code in Webhook, it means your phone number is invalid.

Whatsapp error codes:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/support/error-codes/