# how to check if a phone number is valid whatsapp number in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

so I have a text field that will be used as a view to get phone number from user, say if the phone number is +25678****** , I want to check if this number is a valid whatsapp number or not,i want to restrict the user to input fake whatsapp number, how to do that ?

I have searched every where on google but failed to get a solution

Comment: First any phone number is valid to become a WhatsApp number. So I assume you mean you want to check if this number is registered with WhatsApp. The problem there is its no proof that its my phone number I dont think

Comment: May be a useful read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62213415/how-to-check-if-a-phone-number-is-valid-whatsapp-number-in-android

Comment: exactly i want check if phone number exist on whatsapp platform

Answer (score 0):

Taking the snippet from this api: https://rapidapi.com/inutil-inutil-default/api/bulk-whatsapp-validator/

you can generate the php code that allows you to check if the number is registered on whatsapp or not:

```
  <?php
    
    $curl = curl_init();
    
    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://bulk-whatsapp-validator.p.rapidapi.com/wchk?phone=34605797764",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            "X-RapidAPI-Host: bulk-whatsapp-validator.p.rapidapi.com",
            "X-RapidAPI-Key: your_key_goes_here"
        ],
    ]);
    
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    
    curl_close($curl);
    
    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        echo $response;
    }
```