# How does Android detect that phone has WhatsApp?

Tags: android, whatsapp, android-contacts

I want to know how this feature technically works:

[image: android contact screenshot]

As far as I understand, there is no official API to check it for now. Before v 2.43 API version [there was an official way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62215243/1441592) to check via `/v1/contacts` API of WhatsApp Business. But now it doesn't work.

So how do they do it now ?

Answer (score 0):

Through their `AndroidManifest.xml`. Apps declare which Intents they're able to handle and there's one for making calls / sending SMS. Just call `queryIntentActivities()` on an instance of `PackageManager`, given an `ACTION_{WHATEVER_FEATURE_YOU_WANT_TO_CHECK}` `Intent` configured. This will give you a list of all the matches that would appear as if you tried to make a chooser.

Answer (score 0):

You can check by package name of WhatsApp.

```
boolean isAppInstalled = appInstalledOrNot("com.whatsapp");
```

Using [PackageManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getPackageInfo(java.lang.String,%20android.content.pm.PackageManager.PackageInfoFlags)),

```
private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String packageName) {
    PackageManager packageManagerm = getPackageManager();
    try {
        packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {}
    return false;
}
```